# Find a string with nothing before, and nothing after it

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm working on a terminal-like, using Bootstrap modals, in HTML / JS.
And I need to test several specific strings (like `exit`, `cd ..` ...) 
I'm using this, but I want to trigger an action if the string is 'alone' (nothing before, and nothing after that) :

```
if(event.key != "Enter")
    $('#terminal-text').append(event.key);
else
{
    if($('#terminal-text').text().indexOf("exit") >= 0)
        $('#basicModal2').modal("hide");
    else
        $('#terminal-text').append("<br/>> ")
}
```

But in this case, if the user writes something with exit (like `rustyspoonexit`), it will trigger the action; in this case, it will hide the modal.

I guess I should use Regex but I'm not very familiar with it.
Do you have any ideas about my problem ? Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use the comparison operator `===`:

```
if ($('#terminal-text').text() === 'exit')
```

OR you can also use `regex` but it will be slower:

```
if (/^exit$/.test($('#terminal-text').text()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use start and end anchors:

```
^exit$
```

js Code:

```
if(/^exit$/.test($('#terminal-text').text()))
     $('#basicModal2').modal("hide");
else
    $('#terminal-text').append("<br/>> ");
```

Comment: `===` also is far better than regex